# How to sperate 1 column of date to multiple columns of month in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario in below:

| Name | LoginDate |
| --- | --- |
| Peter | 2020-01-01 |
| Peter | 2020-01-02 |
| Mary | 2020-01-01 |
| Peter | 2020-02-02 |
| Mary | 2020-02-05 |
| Chris | 2020-02-07 |

How to write the SQL which can be re-organized in below

| Name | Jan | Feb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 2 | 1 |
| Mary | 1 | 1 |
| Chris | 0 | 1 |

Appreciated your help!

Comment: You should specify if the counts are to be from every year or just 2020.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [**Month()**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_month.asp) to do it

```
create table login_record(
  name varchar(100),
  login_date date
);

insert into login_record(name,login_date) values
('Peter','2020-01-01'),
('Peter','2020-01-02'),
('Mary','2020-01-01'),
('Peter','2020-02-02'),
('Mary','2020-02-05'),
('Chris','2020-02-07');

SELECT
 name,
 SUM(IF(month(login_date) = 1,1,0)) AS `Jan`,
 SUM(IF(month(login_date) = 2,1,0)) AS `Feb`,
 SUM(IF(month(login_date) = 3,1,0)) AS `Mar`
 -- sum other month
FROM login_record
group by name
order by name
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wXzg5FJw9Gd715KBr8S651/0)